# Solving the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin((2n+1)t)}{\sin t} \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I really don't know how to solve this integral
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin((2n+1)t)}{\sin t} \mathrm{d}t$$
Should I use firstly a formula of $\sin(a+b)$?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can factor out $\sin(2n+1)$.

Comment: I couldn't, $\sin(2n+1)$ is not a const.

Comment: It is with respect to that integral.

Comment: @GitGud You're funny.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sin\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}t} \over \sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t}
=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\expo{\ic\pars{2n + 1}t} - \expo{-\ic\pars{2n + 1}t}
\over \expo{\ic t} - \expo{-\ic t}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] = & \ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{-2nt\,\ic}{\expo{\ic\pars{2n + 1}2t} - 1
\over \expo{2\ic t} - 1}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{-2nt\,\ic}\sum_{k = 0}^{2n}\expo{2\ic k t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] = & \ \sum_{k = -n}^{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{2kt\,\ic}\,\dd t
= \sum_{k = -n}^{-1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{2kt\,\ic}\,\dd t + {\pi \over 2}
+ \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{2kt\,\ic}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] = &\ {\pi \over 2}
+ 2\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{2kt}\,\dd t}^{\ds{=\ 0}}
= \color{#00f}{\Large{\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}

Comment: This is really just using the Dirichlet kernel without explaining what is going on. Words are useful. =/

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I was not aware of that. I'm a physicist. I just follow step by step what I believed it was the way to find a solution. Indeed, I was surprised by the simple result. Any way, I learnt something new today. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the Dirichlet integral and the integrand sin(2n+1)t/sint = 1 + 2cos2t + 2cos4t + ...+ 2cos(2nt). You can use this to integrate term by term and the answer is: pi/2

Comment: Please add Latex in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a general very useful fact that $$D_n(t)=\sum_{k=-n}^ne^{ikt}=1+2\sum_{k=1}^n\cos kt=\frac{\sin\left(n+\frac 1 2\right)t}{\sin \frac t 2}$$

You can go head and try to prove it. $D_n(t)$ is known as the Dirichlet kernel, and is widely used in Fourier Theory. In particular, if $S_n(t)$ is the $n$-th partial sum of $f$'s  Fourier series, $$S_n(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(u)D_n(u-t)dt=(f\ast D_n)(t)$$

Comment: Oh I was going to answer, but you went faster.(+1)

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle I_n=\int_0^{\dfrac\pi2} \frac{\sin((2n+1)t)}{\sin t} \mathrm{d}t$

$\displaystyle I_n-I_{n-1}=\int_0^{\dfrac\pi2} \frac{\sin((2n+1)t)-\sin((2n-1)t)}{\sin t} \mathrm{d}t$

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas, $\displaystyle \sin((2n+1)t)-\sin((2n-1)t)=2\sin t\cos2nt $

$\displaystyle\implies I_n-I_{n-1}=2\int_0^{\dfrac\pi2}\cos2nt\mathrm{d}t=\cdots =0$

Now, $\displaystyle I_0=\int_0^{\dfrac\pi2} \frac{\sin((2\cdot+1)t)}{\sin t} \mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{\dfrac\pi2}\mathrm{d}t=\cdots$